# Show all documents of Restricted Readers users in a web part SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have some users and added to "Restricted Readers" permission level, created some document libraries and added these users to access their related documents library documents.

I want to display all documents in their document library on custom web part. Please provide any help using rest api or C# code.